# NGRX component store selector by parameter does not always fire

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an objects map structure that I keep in the component store:

```
{
   id1: {
    name: param1,
    value: 45
   },
   id2: {
    name: param2,
    value: 567
   }
}
```

I have selector:

```
objectsMap$: Observable<ObjectsMapModel> = this.select(
    (state) => state.objectsMap
);
```

and this works perfectly, fire every time I changed the structure of the whole map.

```
readonly setObjectMap = this.updater((state: MainStore, data: ObjectMapModel) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        objectMap: data
    };
});
```

I also have an updater which change the value of a single object:

```
 readonly setSingleObjectValue = this.updater((state: MainStore, data: ObjectModel) => {
    const objectMapWithNewValue = state.objectMap[data.id] = {...data}
    return {
        ...state,
        objectMap: objectMapWithNewValue 
    };
});
```

Now I need a selector per single object in the object map.
I have a lot of objects here and it is not possible to create selectors one by one. For this purpose I found 3 ways:

1. Solution which does not work and I do not understand why.

   ```
    objectById(id: string): Observable<ObjectModel> {
        return this.select(state => {
            // method never enter this line
            return state.objectMap[id]
        })
    }
    objectById$ = this.objectById;
   ```
2. This solution works, but my reducer first needs to change the whole objectMap structure to fire objectMap selector first and after that change the reference/update value of my object. But changing the reference of the whole objectMap structure is not ok for me, I do not want that.

   ```
   objectById2(id: string): Observable<ObjectModel> {
        return this.select(this.objectsMap$,
        (objectsMap) => {
            return objectsMap[id];
        }
    )}
    objectById2$ = this.objectById2;
   ```
3. The third solution I did to test, just for one object. It works fine but I do not need it since I want a dynamic method for object subscription by id (as 1) or 2) above).

   ```
   objectWithId1$: Observable<ObjectModel> = this.select(
       (state) => {
           return state.parameterDescription['id1']
       }
   )
   ```

2 and 3 works, but I do not need them. I do not understand why solution 1 does not work?